# All admin and frontend pages are working except admin dashboard in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, All admin and front end pages are working except admin dashboard is now working... i changed in htaccess. permalinks and checked in theme and plugin

On dashboard below error is coming

The yve.today page isn’t working

yve.today is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Please help how to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have changed something either in your functions.php of theme or installed a new plugin so because of that you are seeing this error.

A 500 error means there is something wrong with a piece of code being executed, this would in your case (most likely) be caused by a plugin or your theme, the only way to test this is through deactivation.

I suggest to access your server via FTP, or a file manager in your hosting account’s control panel, navigate to /wp-content/themes/WhatYourThemeName/, open `functions.php` and remove the code you added recently. or find it the recent plugin have installed recently and deactivate that to check.

I personally would recommend **installing WordPress locally** and testing any changes there before you do it on your live site.